# SharePoint site space usage

Tags: sharepoint, vba, moss

I would like to find out how much space my group's SharePoint site uses (files + version history). However, I only have administrative access to my site, not the entire SharePoint instance, so I have to come up with my own solution. I'm interested in the total, but usage per individual file is also fine.

I've googled everything I could think of but couldn't find much that would help. SharePoint programming seems out of the question since I don't have access to the machine. SharePoint Web Services looked promising but none of the services provided seem to give me what I need. I also found a VBA library that lets me list the versions of a document: Office.DocumentLibraryVersion. However, this type does not include a "size" property - why not?

Anyway, I would be happy with either of the following solutions:

- A library or API to be used from VBA, VB, or C# (or any other language, for that matter)
- A SharePoint Web Service that provides file size/space usage information
- A completely crazy script that uses http to iterate through all the folders/files/versions in the library and does insane pattern matching to figure out the size of each file, then adds them together and returns the grand total (SharePoint du)

I figured SO is the best forum for this question, but a non-programmatic solution is just as welcome. Basically, anything you can come up with would help. At this point, even "this is not possible" would be useful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a hidden page that does this... Cannot find it right now.
Check the 1033 directory and similar to /layouts/usage.aspx.
That page links to /layouts/storman.aspx. Unfortunately that page does not work if your site collection does not have a quota.

Comment: There is a /_layouts/usage.aspx but it tells me I don't have access. I've added that info to my request to the site administrators. 

It looks like I'll be manually calculating file sizes. Thanks a lot, Nat.

Comment: The usage.aspx is site usage only, not the sizing I think.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Site Settings / Site Usage Report.

If what you are looking for is not there, I don't think you can do it with your level of access.

Comment: You're probably right. I think it's under Site Collection Administration (which I don't have access to). Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

got to siote actions--> site administration-->site usage reports-->
you can get the site usgae report

if you want to get it in excel chart--> open your site in sharepoint designer-->site-->reports-->usage-->then  you can get

1. usage summary
2. monthly summary
3. daily summary
4. daily page hits
   etc

Comment: Thank you, Radhika. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like any of those gives me the total space usage.